# Render doc, xlsx, ppt document in Angular Application

Tags: angular, xlsx

I have office documents like Docx, xlsx, ppt in a remote server, is it possible to render these files as it is in the Angular web app in read-only mode.

Also to render files saved in my google drive account in Angular application.

Is it possible to achieve the above functionality in Angular?

Answer (score 1):

yes see this, Here you just have to pass the content url
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.